# Validation for must_be_below_user_limit allowing users to exceed user limit Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

So I Am building a multi-tenant app in Rails 4 with Apartment, Devise and Devise_Invitable.

I Want to Limit the number of users in each account based on the plan type.

When I create a user the validation should look to see that the user count is below the plan limit and if it is equal to the plan limit:

A) Not Allow the user to be created
B) show a flash message that tells the owner / admin they need to upgrade their account.

As it sits now the validation is not throwing an error on create, but its also not preventing the user from being created either.

**Here is the User Model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Constants & Enums
  USER_LIMITS = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    #Plan Name      #Auth Users
    responder:        6,
    first_responder:  12,
    patrol_pro:       30,
    guardian:         60
  )

  # Before Actions

  # Devise Modules
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :invitable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :account, optional: true

  # Validations
  validates :f_name, presence: true
  validates :l_name, presence: true
  validates :date_of_birth, presence: true

  validate :must_be_below_user_limit, on: [:create]

  # Custom Methods
  def full_name
    l_name.upcase + ", " + f_name
  end

  def user_limit
    USER_LIMITS[account.plan.plan_type]
  end

  def must_be_below_user_limit
    if account.present? && persisted? && account.users.size > user_limit
     errors[:user_limit] = "can not have more than #{user_limit} users"
    end
  end

end
```

**Here is the Plan model:**

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  # Enum & Constants
  enum plan_type: [:responder, :first_responder, :patrol_pro, :guardian]

  USER_LIMITS = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    #Plan Name      #Auth Users
    responder:        6,
    first_responder:  12,
    patrol_pro:       30,
    guardian:         60
  )

  # Before Actions

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :account, optional: true

  # Validations

end
```

**and here is the Account model:**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader[:image]
  # Constants
  RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS = %w(www patrolvault admin test type taurenapplabs taurenmaterialservices)

  # Before Actions
  before_validation :downcase_subdomain

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
  has_many :users

  # Validations
  validates :owner, presence: true

  validates :subdomain, presence: true,
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                        format: { with: /\A[\w\-]+\Z/i, message: 'Contains invalid characters.' },
                        exclusion: { in: RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS, message: 'Restricted domain name'}

  has_one :plan
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :plan

  private

  def downcase_subdomain
    self.subdomain = self.subdomain.downcase
  end

end
```

Like I said, its not that the validation is erroring out.. but its also not preventing the user from being created. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `account.users.size` this will only be true if the latest user has already been created... so that's the error. You could try `>=` instead of just `>`. I'd also be thinking of adding a `before_save` onto the `User` model that stops the user from being saved at all if the limit has been reached.

Comment: @TarynEast so should I change the validates to a before_save? or also add a before save to call the :must_be_below_user_limit as well? and the thought process on the > was to not allow a user to be created if the count was equal to the user_limit.

Comment: How are you saving the plan models? (create, save, etc)

Comment: the plan is created through the account, its just a dropdown select box with the plan name in it i think the validations should be done in the users model and just reference the plan name

Comment: "or also add a before save to call the :must_be_below_user_limit as well" At this stage I'd add it and see if it helps. "and the thought process on the > was to not allow a user to be created if the count was equal to the user_limit." yes but that's not what is actually happening... it's allowing it until the user count is *greater* than the limit... and you want it to fail the validation if the user-count *equals* (or greater than) the limit...

Comment: @TarynEast ahh gotchya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `retrun false` in the `must_be_below_user_limit` method.

```
def must_be_below_user_limit
  if account.present? && persisted? && account.users.count > user_limit
    errors[:user_limit] = "can not have more than #{user_limit} users"
    return false
  end
end
```